# Problems with a constant term in an Integrate command

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When asking Mathematica to integrate a function with `Integrate`, I'm getting drastically different results depending on whether I have a proportionality constant inside or outside of the `Integrate` command.

To summarize: I'm attempting to define a probability distribution from the function `ds`:

```
ds[e_, th_]:= a^2r^2(P[e, th]^2)(P[e, th]+P[e, th]^(-1)-1+Cos[th]^2)/2
```

with

```
P[e_, th_]:=1/(1+(e/(m*c^2))(1-Cos[th]))
```

and `a`, `r`, `c`, and `m` real constants, as follows:

```
c = 3*10^(8);
h = 1.05*10^(-34);
m = 9.11*10^(-31);
r = h/(m*c);
a = 7.30*10^(-3);
```

I'd like the distribution to give the probability density function for values of `th` from 0 to 2pi. However, for this to work properly with `ProbabilityDistribution`, `ds` needs to be normalized. I should be able to do this by integrating `ds` over the relevant interval (for a specific `e`, in this case 10^(-15)) and dividing `ds` by the resulting constant:

```
s=Integrate[ds[10^(-15), th],{th, 0, 2 Pi}]

1.66118*10^(-25)

ds2[th_]:=ds[10^(-15), th]/s
```

However, something seems to be broken in this solution. If I define a probability distribution in terms of `ds2`, it doesn't act as though the distribution is normalized, and instead returns values far outside the desired range. To diagnose the problem, I've tried integrating `ds` divided by `s`. Here's what I'm getting: When `s` is outside the integral, I have

```
Integrate[ds[10^(-15), th], {th, 0, 2 Pi}]/s

1.
```

as expected, but when `s` is inside the integral, I get

```
Integrate[ds[10^(-15), th]/s, {th, 0, 2 Pi}]

0.000217878
```

Because `s` is a constant, moving it inside the integral shouldn't affect the result, so clearly something is going wrong. I've retried the computation with common functions instead of something complicated like `ds`, and don't have any problems there. What might the problem be?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I do not obtain `1.66118*10^(-25)` for `s` but rather an expression dependent on your various constants.  Please provide the values of those constants, if you wish readers to try to reproduce your result for `s`.  Of course, `Integrate[ds[10^(-15), th], {th, 0, 2 Pi}]/s` still yields `1`.

Comment: Values have been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having round-off problems.  One way to eliminate them is by replacing your approximate real numbers by rational numbers, because Mathematica computes results with exact numbers to arbitrary precison.

```
c = 3*10^(8); h = 105*10^(-36); m = 911*10^(-33); r = h/(m*c); a = 730*10^(-5);
```

Then, both normalized integrals yield precisely `1`.